ADB error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): Success
ADB pairing device with VM results in error Success.
Hello all,
i have an issue connecting my Device with adb via wifi.
userinput:$ adb pair 192.168.1.XX
Enter pairing code: 123456
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): Success

For sure, the values were filled out correctly with the information the device printed on the screen. But i also tested an invalid pairing code, resulting in the same error message.
ADB Version:
userinput:$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 35.0.1-11580240
Installed as /home/userinput/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 6.1.0-23-amd64 (x86_64)

I couldnt find this error message with Google, so i asked her, maybe you can help :)
Some additionals about the environment:
The linux system running ADB is a VM on a debian host, thats why i would like to try ADB with Wifi and not with direct USB.
Any help or idears would be verry appreciated :)

Why do you want to pair a VM? Usually emulators/VMs are running locally and thus use direct TCP connection via localhost without pairing (VMs never use USB). What "VM" - emulator an VM image do you use?

Iam using a normal Debian as Host orchestrating all my working VMs with KVM/Qemu like dedicated browser VMs, gaming Windows or programming instances. One of them tries to build a LineageOS and this i would like to flash to my phone. I already did it with scoping the USB to the VM. Nevertheless, the error success is not explaining anything and iam not able to find additional information about this error in the internet so iam not able to use the more usefull Wifi connection as the usb device is changing nearly every adb command so i have to scope it to the VM over and over again.
